# cp command can't parse a path with wildcard in it

Tags: linux, bash

I have a function I wrote in bash that copies files.
It was written so it would be less painful for us to turn our batch scripts that use **xcopy** to bash scripts. This is because the copy commands in Linux work a little bit different.
The function does several things:

- It creates a path to the target directory if it doesn't exist yet.
- It uses `cp` to copy files
- it uses `cp -r` to copy directories.
- it uses `rsync -arv --exclude-from=<FILE>` to copy all the files and folders in a gives directory except the files/folders listed in `FILE`

The problem is, that when I try to copy files with `*` it gives me an error:

> cp: cannot stat 'some dir with * in it': No such file or directory.

I found out that I can instead write something like that: `cp "<dir>/"*".<extension>" "<targetDir>"` and the command itself works. But when I try to pass that to my function, it gets 3 arguments instead of 2.
How can I use the `cp` command in my function while being able to pass a path with wildcard in it? meaning the argument will have double quotes in the beginning of the path and in the end of them, for example: `Copy "<somePath>/*.zip" "<targetDir>"`

```
function Copy {
    echo "number of args is: $#"
    LastStringInPath=$(basename "$2")
    if [[ "$LastStringInPath" != *.* ]]; then
        mkdir -p "$2"
    else
        newDir=$(dirname "$2")
        mkdir -p "newDir"
    fi
    if [ "$#" == "2" ]; then
        echo "Copying $1 to $2"
        if [[ -d $1 ]]; then
            cp -r "$1" "$2"
        else
            cp "$1" "$2"
        fi  
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "Error $? while trying to copy $1 to $2"
            exit 1
        fi
    else
        rsync -arv --exclude-from="$3" "$1" "$2"
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "Error $? while trying to copy $1 to $2"
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
}
```

Comment: The wildcard '*' is resolved by bash and not the cp command.You can use Copy "<somePath>/"\*".zip" "<targetDir>"

Comment: But then my Copy function gets 3 arguments instead of 2.

Comment: For bash, try **cp $(echo $1) $2** in script

Comment: I just pasted your function into my terminal and `Copy foo.* bar/` worked without an error; it created the directory and copied the file over. Are you talking about a filename with a literal `*` in it?

Comment: I'm talking about when you're using quotes withing your path. Sometimes you have spaces in your path so you must use quotrs for that. Try:
Copy "somePath/foo.*" bar/

Comment: @pranav - tried cp $(echo $1) $2, didn't help, maybe variables need to be in quotes?

Comment: I tried it on bash,it worked for me.Do you have #!/bin/bash as first line in the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I couldn't solve this with the suggestions I was given. What was happening is either the * was expanding before it was sent to function or it wouldn't expand at all inside the function. I tried different methods and eventually I decided to rewrite the function so it would instead support multiple arguments.
The expansion of the wild card happens before it sent to my function, and the copy function does all the actions it was doing before while supporting more than one file/dir to copy.

```
function Copy {
argumentsArray=( "$@" )
#Check if last argument has the word exclude, in this case we must use rsync command
if [[ ${argumentsArray[$#-1],,} == exclude:* ]]; then
    mkdir -p "$2"
    #get file name from the argument
    excludeFile=${3#*:}
    rsync -arv --exclude-from="$excludeFile" "$1" "$2"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Error while to copy $1 to $2"
        exit 1
    fi
else
    mkdir -p "${argumentsArray[$#-1]}"

    if [[ -d $1 ]]; then
        cp -r "${argumentsArray[@]}"
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            exit 1
        fi
    else
        cp "${argumentsArray[@]}"
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            exit 1
        fi
    fi   
fi
}
```

Comment: The GNU `cp` command supports passing the destination directory with `-t` for pretty much your scenario.

Comment: As an aside, the idiomatic way to write `foo; if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then ...` is `if ! foo; then ...`

Comment: @tripleee do you mean write something like  if ! cp "${argumentsArray[@]}"; then exit 1

Comment: And what do you mean pass the destination? can you write an example?